# When trying to get page source in c# gives (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: c#

I am trying to download page source of link bellow.

```
http://www.imax.fr/annonces-immobilieres-2.asp?contenu=VENTES-IMMOBILIERES&f=vente-appartement-2-pieces-paris-05-75005&numimmo=11815530&Mrang=4&origine=liste&Nop=1&origine_memo=index
```

BUT it gives me

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

I have tried bellow.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Only a test!");
//webClient.Encoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
string content12 = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.imax.fr/annonces-immobilieres-2.asp?contenu=VENTES-IMMOBILIERES&f=vente-appartement-7-pieces-paris-09-75009&numimmo=11815531&Mrang=4&origine=liste&Nop=1&origine_memo=index");
```

and

```
HttpWebRequest WebRequestObject = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.imax.fr/annonces-immobilieres-2.asp?contenu=VENTES-IMMOBILIERES&f=vente-appartement-2-pieces-paris-05-75005&numimmo=11815530&Mrang=4&origine=liste&Nop=1&origine_memo=index");
WebRequestObject.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
WebRequestObject.Proxy = null;
HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)WebRequestObject.GetResponse();
```

But in both case it gives same error so is there any way to resolve this and get page source in c#.

EDIT
Same page can be opened with bellow link

http://www.imax.fr/annonces-immobilieres-2.asp?numimmo=11815530

For this link it gives same error

Any help ?

Comment: Check your URL.  It gives me an ODBC error when I try to open that URL in a browser.

Comment: It's not a C# problem. The website seems down.

Comment: URL is working fine in my browser

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is wrong. when you access http://www.imax.fr/annonces-immobilieres-2.asp?contenu=VENTES-IMMOBILIERES&f=vente-appartement-2-pieces-paris-05-75005&numimmo=11815530&Mrang=4&origine=liste&Nop=1&origine_memo=index  you get following error:

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers erreur '80040e14'

[Microsoft][Pilote ODBC Microsoft Access] Erreur de syntaxe dans la clause WHERE.

/annonces-immobilieres-2.asp, ligne 210

verify that URL is correct

however, http://www.imax.fr/annonces-immobilieres-2.asp is accessible. Quite possible you got that link after logging into that and now you are accessing it without logging into. Thats why you are getting this error.

Comment: But URL is working fine in my browser and url is of ads after search on website i am able to download page source of home page but it gives me this error for detail page any solution ?

Comment: To confirm that Instead of that link, use http://www.imax.fr/annonces-immobilieres-2.asp only. That would verify that while accessing it you are having some permission issue.

Comment: Also verify, if you use any proxy while accessing in your browser. If yes. Then use WebClient client = new WebClient();
WebProxy wp = new WebProxy(" proxy server url here");
client.Proxy = wp;

Comment: I want to download page source of link in my question and i am able to open that link with http://www.imax.fr/annonces-immobilieres-2.asp?numimmo=11815392 after removing string from url but still it gives same error

Comment: I mentioned upto .asp.. not the part after ?

Comment: There might be proxy required. Do confirm in your browser.

Comment: Its working upto .asp but i want source for this specific link

Comment: Like I said, there might be some proxy required to access the full URL. Check your browser proxy.

Answer (score 0):

If I go to your link, I get an database error. It states that the Where clause has an error.

The rest of your code is fine and will work while used on other links which are correct :)

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'
>
> [Microsoft] [ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in WHERE clause.
>
> /annonces-immobilieres-2.asp, line 210

Comment: I get this when I copy paste this directly in my browser. http://prntscr.com/8w9das

Comment: try to login first using or send your credentials with it. using WebClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = credentials;

Comment: No login requires for this link

Comment: as you can see, I am getting these errors. Is it maybe region locked?